# CSS: can't select element in header?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm going to die. This is happening to me the second time this week, however I have not idea how i fixed it the first time.

I'm completely helpless and angry. First off, w3c validator says no errors. My SASS Framework for CSS says no errors and I just don't have errors.

this is all I have, the entire page is styled successfully...

```
<body>

<div id="doc">

    <header>

        <div class="inner">

            <div id="branding">
                <a class="logo" href="#">Jihaa</a>
            </div>
```

...and suddenly... i can't select the .logo inside of #branding ARRRRGGGG.

```
#branding .logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    background: red;
}
```

this should do the job right, but no.

Neither does this `header #branding .inner .logo {`or any other possible combination.

Why? I'm completely helpless. No inspecting tool in all my browsers selects the appropriate css. It just doesn't relate to it!

Comment: demo site or http://jsfiddle.net possible?

Comment: `header #branding .inner .logo` this won't work because `.inner` is outside/up `.branding`

Answer (score 4):

`.logo` is an `a` which is an inline element and won't accept `width` and `height`.

Add `display:inline-block;` to the style and it should work.

```
#branding .logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    background: red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT**

To address [@jackJoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624447/jackjoe)'s comment below.

In case you need to support IE6 or 7, you can add the following at the bottom of the rule:

```
zoom:1; 
*display: inline; 
_height: 12px;  //or whatever you need
```

Comment: `inline-block` isn't supported in IE6 + 7.

Comment: True @jackJoe.  But the OP didn't mention he needed to support those browsers.

Comment: the problem is as I said I can't select it. It just doesn't work, doesn't matter if I apply display:block or not. Normally you could select it with a webinspector in a webkit browser and than apply display:block; to see it's working. I cannot even do that.

Comment: Have you tried adding `div#branding a.logo { border:1px solid red; }` to see if you are selecting it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set a width or height for an anchor because it is an inline element.

Use the {display:inline-block;} that Jason Gennaro mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

in this case, if you would like to style the `a` with those properties, you need to specify its display to `block`

```
#branding .logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use the same ids anywhere else in the page.

Also try taking the logo class out of a tag and put it in a div.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think you cannot select it? If its because your height and width are being ignored in your .logo class, that would be because you need to display:block .logo in order for your  to respect them.